Rowbind data with missing values using Arrow in R
I got ginormous amounts of data in 13 csv files that follow the names: kinder_2011.csv to kinder_2023.csv.
I have ensured that all these csv files have the same columns. (matched the names and the same order).
But some of the columns will have missing values (NAs) the entire file. (For example kinder_2011.csv has the column month with just NAs, but kinder_2013.csv has values (integer)). And this happens for almost every column (at some point).
This was my best approach helping myself with AI:
library(arrow)
library(tidyverse)

schema <- schema(
  year = int32(),
  month = int32(),
  mrun = int32(),
  sex_stud = int32(),
  birth_date_stud = int32(),
  school_id = int32(),
  RBD = int32(),
  ID_ESTAB_J = int32(),
  ID_ESTAB_I = int32(),
  NOM_ESTAB = utf8(),
  COD_REG_ESTAB = int32(),
  COD_PRO_ESTAB = int32(),
  COD_COM_ESTAB = int32(),
  NOM_REG_ESTAB = utf8(),
  NOM_REG_A_ESTAB = utf8(),
  NOM_PRO_ESTAB = utf8(),
  NOM_COM_ESTAB = utf8(),
  COD_DEPROV_ESTAB = int32(),
  NOM_DEPROV_ESTAB = utf8(),
  latitude = float64(),
  longitude = float64(),
  rural_establishment = int32(),
  ORIGEN = int32(),
  DEPENDENCIA = int32(),
  NIVEL1 = int32(),
  NIVEL2 = int32(),
  COD_ENSE1_M = int32(),
  COD_GRADO_M = int32(),
  LET_CUR_M = utf8(),
  COD_TIP_CUR_M = int32(),
  COD_DEPE1_M = int32(),
  COD_ENSE2_M = int32(),
  ESTADO_ESTAB_M = int32(),
  CORR_GRU_J = int32(),
  COD_PROG_J = int32(),
  DESC_PROG_J = utf8(),
  COD_NIVEL_J = int32(),
  DESC_NIVEL_J = utf8(),
  COD_MODAL_J = int32(),
  DESC_MODAL_J = utf8(),
  COD_JOR_J = int32(),
  NOM_JOR_J = utf8(),
  DESC_MOD_I = utf8(),
  DESC_NIV_I = utf8(),
  COD_NIVEL_I = int32(),
  COD_GRUPO_I = int32(),
  TIPO_SOSTENEDOR = int32(),
  FORMAL = int32(),
  ASIS_REAL_J = int32(),
  ASIS_POTEN_J = int32(),
  DIAS_TRAB_GRUPO_J = int32()
)

# Leer el dataset considerando los valores faltantes
kinder <- open_delim_dataset(
  paste0(getwd(), "/ChileEduc/data/intermediate/kinder"),
  delim = ";",
  schema = schema, skip = 1
)

kinder2 <- as.data.frame(kinder)

And got this error:

Error in compute.Dataset():
! Invalid: Could not open CSV input source 'C:/Users/XXXX/Dropbox/ChileEduc/data/intermediate/kinder/kinder_2013.csv': Invalid: In CSV column #26: Row #7: CSV conversion error to int32: invalid value ''
ℹ If you have supplied a schema and your data contains a header row, you should supply the argument skip = 1 to prevent the header being read in as data.
Run rlang::last_trace() to see where the error occurred.

How can I fix this? I want to row bind all my files and then just write a parquet or csv file for future analysis.
Note: This is one of the smallest datasets I have and it has a bit more than 9 million of obs.
Thanks in advance!

What happens if you let open_delim_dataset infer the data types from the data by not setting schema? Worst case might be that it's gonna be cast to character which can be fixed afterwards with e.g. as.integer() which can handle '' as NA.

For fast reading and combining multiple CSV files also see https://vroom.r-lib.org/articles/vroom.html#reading-multiple-files

Can you check the column 26 row 7 (and around it) in the kinder_2013.csv? Anything different there? Can you show maybe columns 25:27 and first 10 rows?
